# How to detect MS Access database or SQL Server Compact Edition (MSSQL CE) by a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-ce

I need to detect MS Access database or SQL Server Compact Edition (MSSQL CE) by a query.
I have to be able to know by a query result if I am querying Access or Compact Edition. The application sometimes runs from Windows Mobile and utilizes SQL Server Compact Edition, and other times runs in a desktop utilizing MS Access.

I already know that I can detect the SQL Server Compact Edition version by reading the first bytes of the database file, like stated [here](http://erikej.blogspot.mx/2010/08/sql-server-compact-version-detector.html) and [here too](http://nativemobile.blogspot.mx/2007/12/detecting-sdf-file-version.html)

I also know that I can detect the Sever Version of SQL 2005 or 2008 like explained [also here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10916/different-ways-to-know-sql-servers-version-information.aspx)

I know too that I can check the Windows registry and look for an specific key.

None of these options works for me since I am executing the query from an application running in Windows Mobile.

**Note:** Unfortunately, I cannot execute shell commands or call an external application from the App.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: what language is the application written in, from where you are executing the query to figure this out?

Comment: It is a proprietary script, that runs queries from the App in Windows mobile.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to determine which operating system you're running on since this is how the database type is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling

```
select @@version
```

SQL server will return a value. 
Access will return an error

Comment: That wont Work with SQL Server Compact, but using "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" would Work.